# Will google remove the old caches if noarchive is added to robots.txt?

Tags: google, robots.txt, google-cache, noarchive

If you want google's cache of your site to remain unchanged, is it a good idea to add noarchive to robots.txt? Or will this wipe out your caches?

Comment: As a note if you're interested, Cloudflare free plan includes a more "on demand" sorta cached site. Only comes online if your server is down, whereas G always makes cached available. I'm not affiliated with CF just figured I'd let ya know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, there is no such thing as noarchive in robots.txt. You need to add a meta tag to all pages on which you wish to prevent caching:

```
<meta name="Googlebot" content="noarchive">
```

When you have done that, then Google will stop caching the page entirely and won't show a cache link at all. *There is no way to keep showing the old cache while preventing new caches.*

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is, it could take a month before Google re-crawls your entire site.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_meta_tag' );
function add_meta_tag() {
echo '<META NAME="GOOGLEBOT" CONTENT="NOARCHIVE">';
}
```

1. Add this PHP to your child themes functions file
2. Then re-build your site map
3. And submit the sitemap URL to Webmaster Tools > Crawl > Fetch as Google

Comment: Whoe man, please note that the above script is for WordPress. We don't need folks dropping in undefined functions to their non-wp platforms. Also you are better off doing that in htaccess using X_ROBOTS header for a fully encompassed flag. Think media files and stuff.